# How do I make sure that my Lit element component props are properly typed in Typescript

Tags: typescript, lit

I have a library where I want to create a button for all the different frameworks out there. All of those components props should have a single source of truth from a Typescript interface:

```
interface BaseButton {
    tiny: boolean;
    color: string;
}
```

How can I make sure that my Lit element properties are properly typed according to that interface?

```
@customElement("my-button")
export class MyButton extends LitElement {
    @property({ type: Boolean })
    tiny = true;

    @property({ type: String })
    color = "red";
    ....
}
```

Comment: `implements`? I'm not sure what you're asking about. Is it the decorators? I don't think you can make those depend on the type in the interface.

Comment: So, as in React you do something like: 
`export const MyButton: FC<BaseButton> = ({
    tiny,
    color,
}) => {
...
}` and the build would fail if you were to add a different prop, how do I achieve the same here?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the interface.

General example:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  foo: boolean;
  bar: string;
}

// Invalid
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  // TS2416
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
}

// Valid
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  foo: boolean;
  bar: string;
}
```

Your code:

```js
export class MyButton extends LitElement implements BaseButton {...
```